# How to use the function wald.test in R

Tags: r, function, package, new-operator

as I am quite new to using R I am having a question that might seem rather stupid to most of you professional guys but still I would be really thankful for help. My question aims at the use of the function "wald.test" from the package "aod". I want to test a specific number of terms here but I am not quite sure whether I determine them correctly. What I did is the following:

```
library(aod)

HAC.coef <- Montelimar.lm$coefficients
HAC.coef <- Montelimar.lm.HAC[1:25,1]
```

This means that I extracted the coefficients from a linear model I fitted which were then overwritten by the coefficients that are corrected for HAC. This worked out perfectly and looks like this:

```
(Intercept)             t     temp_auto       dum.jan       dum.feb       dum.mar       dum.apr       dum.may 
 4.722586e+00  1.079707e-05  7.855185e-01 -3.846811e+00 -3.515380e+00 -2.779311e+00 -2.223969e+00 -1.349737e+00 
      dum.jun       dum.aug       dum.sep       dum.oct       dum.nov       dum.dec     t:dum.jan     t:dum.feb 
-5.898149e-01 -2.577604e-01 -9.102143e-01 -2.023789e+00 -3.090368e+00 -3.862059e+00 -2.483651e-06 -3.625246e-06 
    t:dum.mar     t:dum.apr     t:dum.may     t:dum.jun     t:dum.aug     t:dum.sep     t:dum.oct     t:dum.nov 
-2.652827e-06 -1.630459e-06 -4.808934e-07  2.486546e-06  1.039740e-06 -5.281872e-06 -1.195083e-06 -3.936812e-06 
    t:dum.dec 
 1.203809e-06
```

Now I want to test all the coefficients containing a t. This are the 2 and the 15 to the 25th term. So I was wondering if this code is doing the trick:

```
wald.trend <- wald.test(Sigma=vcovHAC(Montelimar.lm),b=HAC.coef,Term=c(2,15:25))
```

I am especially concerned about the "Term=.." part as I am not sure whether I understood that correctly.

It would be very helpful if someone could help me, even though this might be trivial for the majority of community members.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: The arguments appear to be delivered correctly. Didn't you get a result? What was it?  What's not clear is what you mean by " I want to test all the coefficients".

Comment: There were results but I was not sure whether they are from the test I planned to conduct. If I used the command correctly then I am really happy. I was just unsure about it. :)

Comment: It's still not clear whether you understand the difference between Wald tests and likelihood ratio tests. That difference may bear on interpretation and validity regarding tests of "all the coefficients", which is still ambiguous in your question..

Comment: I was not referring to testing “all coefficients”. I mean I want to test a subset of coefficients containing the t as an indice of time. I am really sorry if this was unintelligible but I just wanted to conduct a test of a subset of my coefficients. :)

Comment: Still unclear. Saying “a test of a subset of coefficients “ does not make clear what’s to be tested. Look up the difference between Wald and LR tests.